# What algorithm to choose order of university courses?

Tags: algorithms, recommender-system, graphs

If I want to suggest a course path for a student who wanted to be a chemical engineering where each degree has to go through certain mandatory courses like math ,physics chemistry . Again to complete these mandatory courses there is various pre-requisite courses . Again I have to suggest a best course path by breaking the course in season like fall,winter and summer etc according credit points rule of university .

So just wanted understand which algorithm or approach i should choose to solve this kind of problem .

I thought of choosing heuristic approach find the best path but there is various mandatory courses and student has to complete each mandatory courses and heuristic A* path finding algorithm works if you know the source and destination  .

Again I thought of using Travelling Salesman problem approach where student has to travel mandatory course but in this case problem is each mandatory courses has again various path . so how do approach about this .

Thanks in advance , Please guide me friends . appreciate your earl reply.

Comment: This can be potentially be modeled as a critical path problem. But for any optimization problem, first clearly state three things: Given Data, Objective i.e. what exactly you are trying to min /maximize , constraints for eg.credits, time, pre-requisites etc. This will also help identify the right algorithm/ approach.